# Helm error `error calling index: value is nil; should be of type string` when this error did not appear before

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have been deploying my code with no issues; however, I have now began to receive errors when deploying from my terminal with the following:

`<index .Values.common .Values.deploy_target>: error calling index: value is nil; should be of type string`

Here is my code to get a better idea. I have my `deployment.yaml` and `Values.yml`. Here is an excerpt of the code:

`deployment.yaml`

```
          # Common Environment variables
          {{- with (index .Values.common .Values.deploy_target) }}
            {{- range .env_vars }}
            - name: {{.name}}
              value: "{{.value}}"
            {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
```

`values.yaml`

```
common:
  dev:
    env_vars:
      - name: foo
        value: bar
      - name: foo
        value: bar
  qa:
    env_vars:
      - name: foo
        value: bar
      - name: foo
        value: bar
  production:
    env_vars:
      - name: foo
        value: bar
      - name: foo
        value: bar
```

The command I use to install the service is the following:

`helm upgrade --install foo-bar .helm/folder -n beta`

I would appreciate anyone that can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow logic looks correct but it seems like `.Values.deploy_target` is not set in your `values.yaml` which is why it's nil when it expects a string. Make sure `.Values.deploy_target` exists.

Side note: you can also pipe rather than place quotes around -> `value: {{.value | quote}}`

Comment: Thanks JasonY, let me try this out.